# Trigonometric Equation - can this be solved using complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, sum-of-squares-method

How do I solve the following:

$\cos (12x) = 5 \sin (3x) + 9 \tan^2( x )+ \cot ^2 (x)$ for $x \in (0,360)$

I tried converting cos and sin term into single angle i.e. into x but the equation becomes messy. Any elegant solution at hand?

Comment: Should we assume $x$ to be in radians? Or degree?

Comment: $x$ should be in degrees.

Comment: The query is comprehensively answered by the already existing responses, but begs the question: when facing a problem *similar* to this, if no elegance occurs to you in the first 15-30 minutes, what do you do?  With this problem, I would have focused on the fact that $12 = (3 \times 4)$ and that $\cos(4u)$ should be expressible as a polynomial involving $\cos(u)$ and $\sin(u)$.  Setting $u = 3x$ that would have (at least) eliminated consideration of any trig functions that did not involve $x$ or $3x$.  ...see next comment

Comment: The next step would have been to take a *long* look at the result and then decide whether each occurrence of $\cos(3x)$ or $\sin(3x)$ should itself be converted into a polynomial involving $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$.  One of the most powerful weapons that a math problem solver has is a willingness to **get down in the mud**.

Comment: There is a *hidden* point.  Take a long look at the elegance of Albus Dumbledore's answer.  Suppose that you are attacking such a problem that has a very elegant simplification that you totally overlook.  Often, in such a case, the **inelegant** approach will result in less work than you would have surmised, because the **simplification** must eventually occur - that is, given the answer that Albus Dumbledore discovered, that answer would have **had** to eventually surface, regardless of how inelegantly you are attacking the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not much different form Toby Mak's answer but  We could infact rewrite the given equaltion in the following form  $$1-\cos 12x+5(\sin 3x+1)+{\left( 3\tan x-\cot x\right)}^2=0$$ as each terms is $\ge 0$ we must have that each term must be zero ,

can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum value of $9 \tan^2 x + \cot^2 x$ is $2 \sqrt{9 \tan^2 x \cot^2 x} = 6$ by AM-GM for all real $x$, as $u^2 ≥ 0, u \in \mathbb R$. Thus $\cos(12x) - \left(5 \sin(3x) + 9 \tan^2 x + \cot^2 x \right)$ is bounded above by $g(x)=\cos(12x) - \left(5 \sin(3x) + 6 \right)$.

Now $g(x)$ is again bounded above by $1 -5 (-1) - 6 = 0$. Hence you just need to solve $g(x) = 0$, but as $\cos(12x) ≤ 1$, $5 \sin(3x) + 6 ≥ 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, this implies:

$$\cos(12x) = 1, 5 \sin(3x) + 6 = 1$$

Comment: $g(x) = \cos (12x) - 5\sin(3x) - 6 \le 1 + 5 - 6 =0$ does not require the derivative; and it also hints at when equality holds.

Comment: A slight suggestion :wouldnt it better to write the given equation as $$1-\cos 12x+5(\sin 3x+1)+{\left( 3\tan x-\cot x\right)}^2=0$$ which impkies eqach term must be zero.........

Comment: Thank you everyone for suggesting these improvements: if you write these answers I can upvote them.

Answer (score 0):

$$a+b\geq 2\sqrt{ab}\\9tan^2x+1cot^2x\geq2\sqrt{9tan^2x\times 1cot^2x}=6$$so
$$cos(12x)-5sin(3x)\geq 6 $$Implicit $$cos(12x)-5sin(3x)\leq \max\{cos(12x)\}+\max \{ -5sin(3x)\}\leq 1+5$$ and only possibilities : $$\begin{cases}cos(12x)=1\\sin(3x)=-1\end{cases}$$